# How can I speed up bulk inserts into MySQL with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I just saw that bulk inserts into a MySQL / MariaDB database is slow with SQLAlchemy (even with [`session.bulk_save_objects(objects)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects)). How can I make faster?

### MVCE

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
import click
import json
import sqlalchemy
import time
import uuid

Base = declarative_base()


class KeyValue(Base):
    __tablename__ = "KeyValue"
    key = Column(String(36), primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Text)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"KeyValue(key='{self.key}', value='{self.value}')"


def run_benchmark(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, n=1000, benchmark_type='orm-bulk'):
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
    connection = engine.connect()

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    keys = [str(uuid.uuid4()) for i in range(n)]
    values = [json.dumps([str(uuid.uuid4()) for _ in range(100)]) for i in range(n)]
    if benchmark_type == 'orm-bulk':
        benchmark_orm_bulk_insert(session, keys, values)
    elif benchmark_type == 'print':
        print_query(keys, values)



def benchmark_orm_bulk_insert(session, keys, values):
    t0 = time.time()
    objects = [
        KeyValue(key=key, value=value)
        for key, value in zip(keys, values)
    ]
    session.bulk_save_objects(objects)
    session.commit()
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f"Inserted {len(keys)} entries in {t1 - t0:0.2f}s with ORM-Bulk "
          f"({len(keys)/(t1 - t0):0.2f} inserts/s).")


def print_query(keys, values):
    print("INSERT INTO KeyValue (`key`, `value`) VALUES")
    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(zip(keys, values)):
        if i == 0:
            print(f"({json.dumps(key)}, {json.dumps(value)})")
        else:
            print(f", ({json.dumps(key)}, {json.dumps(value)})")
    print(";")


@click.command()
@click.option("-n", "n", required=True, type=int)
@click.option(
    "--mode",
    "mode",
    required=True,
    type=click.Choice(["orm-bulk", "print"]),
)
def entry_point(n, mode):
    run_benchmark("mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost/benchmark", n, mode)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    entry_point()
```

This gives:

```
$ python3 benchmark.py -n 10_000 --mode orm-bulk           
Inserted 10000 entries in 3.28s with ORM-Bulk (3048.23 inserts/s).

# Using extended INSERT statements
$ python3 benchmark.py -n 10_000 --mode print > inserts.txt
$ time mysql benchmark < inserts.txt

real    2,93s
user    0,27s
sys 0,03s
```

So the SQLAlchemy bulk insert gets 3048 inserts/s whereas the raw SQL queries have 3412 inserts.

### Related Issue, but not main question

Please note that both numbers are far away from 
the 313,000 inserts / second mentioned in [High-speed inserts with MySQL](https://medium.com/@benmorel/high-speed-inserts-with-mysql-9d3dcd76f723). With

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE KeyValue FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I get to 2.22s execution time (4500 inserts/s), which still is way less. By changing the quotechar from `"` to `'` (reducing the escaping a lot), I got to 1.55s (6451 inserts/s).

Changing the [`bulk_insert_buffer_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size) to 256MB also didn't help ([howto](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54207/25983))

Changing the MySQL storage engine from InnoDB to MyISAM changed the speed to 0.32 sec (31250 inserts/s)!

Trying out other storage engines with 3 runs each:

- CSV (does not allow any key!): 0.40s / 0.53s / 0.46s
- Aria (without primary key): 0.38s / 0.38s / 0.38s
- Aria (with primary key): 0.47s / 0.49s / 0.45s
- MyISAM (without primary key): 0.26s / 0.26s / 0.26s => 38461 inserts/s
- MyISAM (with primary key): 0.32s / 0.30s / 0.29s